# Mercurial - Look into history of file without updating

Tags: mercurial, history

I'm working in this file and I come across a piece of code which I think has changed at some point in history, and I would like to know where it changed.

It's a pretty big file with a lot of history, so when I use hg diff, I get a enormous list and I don't think it's efficient to search through that.

It would be really neat if I can look into an old revision of the file, to see what the file looked like at a certain point in time. Then I can see how the code worked back then so I can conclude how the bug evolved. Of course, I want to do this without updating the file, because I'm currently working in it and have made changes in it.

So, is there any way you can look into the history of a file without updating it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few tools to help you:

To get the history of a file you can just use `hg log FILE` which is probably the best starting point.

You can also use `hg annotate FILE` which lists every line in the file and says which revision changed it to be like it currently is.  It can also take a revision using the `--rev REV` command tail to look at older versions of the file.

To just list the contents of a file at a given revision you can use `hg cat FILE --rev REV`.

If it proves too hard to track down the bug using those tools, you can just clone your repository somewhere else and use `hg bisect` to track it down.

Comment: Thanks, hg cat FILE --rev REV was what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

hg bisect lets you find the changeset that intoduced a problem. To start the search run the `hg bisect --reset` command.  It is well document in **Mercurial: The Definitive Guide**.